Which tool to disassemble / reassemble the lock nut on this Shimano HB M8000 Deore XT front hub?
I have a Shimano HB M8000 Deore XT front hub.
https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-HB-M8000-3868.pdf

I noticed the lock nuts on both sides are round. What tools are required to disassemble / reassemble this type of hub. I know I need a cone wrench (flat spanner). But for the lock nut what tool is required?
Maybe these pictures will help (excuse the amateur terminology)





I asked a related question
Does Shimano document the tool sizes for their parts?
Not sure if I should have combined the questions.

Tools are documented for Shimano, and that sometimes includes sizes.
See https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/HB0002/DM-HB0002-15-ENG.pdf. Your HB-M8000 is on page 19.
You will need a TL-HS22 tool and a 5 mm allen key. Image search results show the TL-HS22 as 17/24 mm.
On this page you also find the recommended torque and type of grease.
How to find this manual? Start at https://si.shimano.com/en/manual/search. Put HB-M8000 in the first search box and check DM for Dealer's Manual.

The sources in this answer are excellent and have all the info you need to work on the M8000 hub.  For some clarity and additional information for readers here:  the M8000 front hub is disassembled from the right/drive side. Here the 5mm Allen key is inserted into outer lock nut and rotated CCW while the cone nut is held fast with a 17mm hub spanner (or the 17mm side of the TL-HS22, a 2-sided cone wrench. 24mm is the wrench  opposite the 17mm). The axle with the left side's cone assembly can then be removed, completing the most possible disassembly.
